# Java Springboot+Gradle: How to "block" service specific URL from the web browser's address bar

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, spring-boot, gradle

Is there a way that a certain URL can be "blocked" from entering in the web browser?  We have two (2) Springboot + Gradle projects in Eclipse IDE:

1. (Main App) The first one contains the user interface, e.g. .jsp, .java (servlets, SpringApplication main app, etc.), .css, .html, .js, etc. (port 8181 in Tomcat), and
2. (Main App's Services) The other one are the services that the user interface consumes (port 8282 in Tomcat).  But every time I try to write it in a other tab, for example:

http://localhost:8282/myservice/myAccountDetails

This will display a JSON file result in the browser.

The team (*I was just an additional, and not the original member though, thus I am still studying their code*) wants me to make all **localhost:8282/myservice/*** inaccessible, because they want the services to be accessible only going to the main application.  They prefer either to:

1. declare HTTP code 403 or
2. prompt a user name and password, that, if entered correctly, will display the "plain" JSON file.

I prefer to use the HTTP code 403.  But is there any reading I could follow in order to achieve this?  I have a code that works successfully (making it HTTP code 403), but unfortunately, every time I add this code from the main app's services (*some codes came from here at stackoverflow and other sites*), the main program cease to login properly (i.e. it no longer logins successfully, thus it no longer views other services).

Thank you for any tips and/or resources you could share.

Have a blessed day.

Comment: Are the services used directy by the main app, or by the user’s browser?

Comment: This shouldn't be done at the application layer. The 8282 port should just not be accessible from the outside, at the networking layer. Configure your firewall.

Comment: @JB.  Can you please give me instruction step by step how to set this in Tomcat using Eclipse?  Is this not achievable in code?  I kept on practicing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but I can't get the "right blend."

Comment: @Roger. The services are used by the main app, for example, typing localhost:8181 give the main apps login page, when the user click the login button, through external JS, access localhost:8282/myservice/sign service.

Comment: If the external JS accesses the services they must be accessible from the outside, by the user running the JS. You could perhaps have your JS send additional tokens and return 403 if it isn't sent, but why do you want to prevent access the the JSON?